# Unable to reject an edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I came across a pending edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44189089/i-keep-gettin-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-bs4-error) which appears to have conflicted with another edit, but I'm unable to reject it. After opening up the in-post review modal by clicking the edit link, the Reject button doesn't submit the form (I've checked network traffic in web inspector) and it just sits there saying "Rejecting..." I've reloaded the page a few times and cleared cache; no JavaScript errors are happening either. Any ideas what's going on?

Visiting the specific suggested edit in the review queue worked as expected.

Comment: Why did you link the question, and not the suggested edit?

Comment: Yep, I got the same result on Chrome/Win10.

Comment: Uh yeah [me too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349727/560648)

Comment: _"Any ideas what's going on?"_ Lack of regression testing before publishing an updated version of the code to production? Ahem. I mean why spend money _testing_ your code when you have an army of metamoaners like us happy to do it for you for free!

Comment: So interestingly, the in-question review modal failed for me, but manually entering the review id (16234790) to get to it in the review queue (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16234790) fix it.  Weird.

Comment: @Servy I didn't see this in the review queue, I came across it in the question itself. Don't know how to get a link from there.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition that is what Netscape did, right? They are now gone ...

Comment: @miken32 I observed network traffic, grabbed an id that looked promising, then URL hacked my way to the specific review item.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I did the opposite; I went to review, checked that Reject works (without following through) then clicked through to the question and retested there :)

Comment: @Servy: Because if you link to the suggested edit it works. OP is linking to the bug reproducer, as is appropriate.