# Reject edit popup broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

Currently, when I click "Reject" from the review popup, the button changes to "Rejecting..." and that's it. Nothing else <strike>matters</strike> happens.

[image: Animation of problem]

This is on question pages only; seems ok from review queue.

Chrome 58, Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to reject an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349726/unable-to-reject-an-edit)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Bah. But I made a nice GIF! :D

Comment: I actually think this is the better-formed post, so I'm voting the duplicate the other way around.

Comment: Happens for me as well, Chrome 58 / macOS Sierra. Nothing in the JS console.

Comment: GIF is nice, but lack of animated hand drawn red circle makes it -1.

Comment: Reproducible: Chrome 58 on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Looks as if the second popup with the reject reasons opens in the background. [Screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/aXMkQY0vu.png)

Comment: Workaround: Find div with id `rejection-popup` and increase its z-index to 9000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And now, with an update from the "it's a bad idea to hardcode CSS in Javascript" desk...

We're in the process of paying down a bunch of styling tech debt, including standardizing z-indexes. A line of Javascript that set the z-index on the rejection popup to 2000 was overlooked. The fix is live now - and going forward we're calculating the appropriate z-index based on the `.lightbox` background div to prevent another break *next* time we refactor styles.